# Does mapping Gtk2::Gdk::Pixbuf produce a memory leak on perl?

Tags: perl, gtk2

I need to load multiple sizes from same image, see my perl gtk2 code:

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Gtk2;
use Glib qw/TRUE FALSE/;

sub cb_destroy
{
    Gtk2->main_quit;
}

sub Main {
    my $title = shift;
    Gtk2->init;
    my $window = Gtk2::Window->new('toplevel');
    $window->set_default_icon_list(
        map {
            Gtk2::Gdk::Pixbuf->new_from_file_at_scale(
                'cat-purr-icon_128.png', $_, $_, TRUE )
        } 128, 64, 48, 32, 16
    );
    $window->signal_connect(destroy => \&cb_destroy);
    $window->show_all;
    Gtk2->main;
    return 0;
}

exit Main('Testing');
```

The code works as expected, but I would like to know if `map` method of calling multiple times [Gtk2::Gdk::Pixbuf->new_from_file_at_scale](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/pod/Gtk2/Gdk/Pixbuf.html#pixbuf_Gtk2_Gdk_Pixb3) in [Gtk2::Window->set_default_icon_list](http://gtk2-perl.sourceforge.net/doc/pod/Gtk2/Window.html#_window_set_default_1) produces memory leak? If so, what would be an alternative way to deal with my goal: use multiple sizes from the same image.

Comment: *"... I would like to know if map method .. produces a memory leak"* Why do you think that? The map method just builds a list of pixbufs that is then passed to `set_default_icon_list()`. Since the code works as expected, `set_default_icon_list()` probably makes a copy of the pixbufs?

Comment: @HåkonHægland, I think because most of **gdk_pixbuf_new_** family functions in C, after the used, they need to clean up with `g_object_unref`. That´s why I´m asking.

Comment: The fact that map is used is irrelevant. The question is whether the creation of an Gtk2::Gdk::Pixbuf object needs to be followed up with an explicit destruction. You should never have to do that in Perl, and a quick look at the code suggests this library is no exception.